Specifying program length with regards to intermission
If a theater program / brochure says "2 hours with intermission", does it mean the time for intermission is included in the 2 hours?
What should the program / brochure say if the intermission is in addition to the 2 hours, meaning that from the time the program starts to the time the program ends, the elapsed time is 2 hours PLUS the length of the intermission (which is unspecified because they don't want to determine it in advance)?

A running time given in a programme shows the time from start to finish, and 'with intermission' includes the intermission. if there is no intermission it will say so e..g.  Run time: 2 hours, no intermission (The Merchant of Venice, Classic Stage Company, New York, December 2024)

@MichaelHarvey What would the program say if the 2 hours does NOT include the length of the intermission?  Would they say "2 hours plus intermission"?

They would not. The time indicated is the time between sitting down at the start and (more or less) getting up at the end.

Yes, that is what it means.  The time from the start to the end of the performance is (estimated to be) two hours, but part of that time is an intermission.
A running time for a performance is always the time from the start to the end. This is useful if you want to know (for example) when to book a table for dinner after the performance. The amount of time the actors are on stage, excluding any intermission, is not a useful metric for theatre-goers. But if you had to, you could say "...excluding the intermission". This might be useful in a director's script, not in a theatre programme.
This is what it should mean.  But not everyone gets it right, people make mistakes. If my analysis makes you late for dinner, I apologise!

So here, with could be replaced with including. But it typically isn’t.

The meaning is certainly contextual. It is understood as much from thinking about "what information is useful" as from any linguistic clues.

Sometimes the program will say "The performance is 2 hours, including a 15-minute intermission," in which case basic math will tell you the actual performance time if you really must know it. Many opera companies list the time of each part of the program: "Acts I & II (70 min); Intermission (25 min); Acts III & IV (55 min)".

Well... it's what it should mean. As a teen I worked in a movie theater that ran shows with intermissions (e.g., Australia ran with an intermission). Sometimes "with intermission" meant the intermission time was included in the run time, sometimes the run time was for the film, only. While I'd advocate always using it as you've explained, regrettably, it's not that consistent.

Sorry, I was not being clear in my 2nd question: not "outside the two hours".  Isn't intermission by definition is in the middle of the program?  So what the program would say if the length of the intermission is IN ADDITION of the 2 hours?

It wouldn't say that because that's not how we normally describe the length of a performance.  The amount of time the actors are on stage, excluding any intermission, is not a useful metric for theatre-goers. But if you had to, you could say "...excluding the intermission".

@JamesK Thank you.  I have edited the question to make the Q more useful; you may want to edit your answer to address the follow-up question more explicitly, i.e. how to specify in the program / brochure if the intermission length is undetermined.
